# How to import self-signed certificate.ca with private keys in android phone?

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, self-signed-certificate

after creating a self-signed CA file and private keys, I was wondering how to add this ca and key file into an android phone? so far, I have not found a way to import on the phone.

please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Put the CA.der.crt onto the sdcard of your Android device (usually to
  internal one). It should be in root directory.
- Go to Settings / Security / Credential storage and select “Install
  from device storage”.
- The .crt file will be detected and you will be prompted to enter a
  certificate name.
- After importing the certificate, you will find it in Settings /
  Security / Credential storage / Trusted credentials / User.